# how to change variable when filter is on

Tags: php, mysql, variables, permutation

hello i would like to code a filter for an search engine on my site. now i thought it would be the best way to use a simple filter. so my code looks like:

```
}else if ($filter_a === 1){
        $filter = "WHERE `a` LIKE '%$a%'";
}else if ($filter_b === 1){
        $filter = "WHERE `b` LIKE '%$b%'";
}else if ($filter_c === 1){
        $filter = "WHERE `c` LIKE '%$c%'";
...
}else if ( ($filter_a === 1) && ($filter_b === 1) ){
        $filter = "WHERE `a` LIKE '%$a%' AND `b` LIKE '%$b%'";
}else if ( ($filter_a === 1) && ($filter_c === 1) ){
        $filter = "WHERE `a` LIKE '%$a%' AND `c` LIKE '%$c%'";
... and so on
```

the problem is that i have 5x `N` so the permutation of this would be 120 possibilites for `$filter`

is there a way how i can solve this? if there is someone who could help me out i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this way?

```
if ($filter_a === 1) {
        $filter[] = "`a` LIKE '%$a%'";
}
if ($filter_b === 1) {
        $filter[] = "`b` LIKE '%$b%'";
}
if ($filter_c === 1) {
        $filter[] = "`c` LIKE '%$c%'";
}
$filter = "WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $filter);
```